# Teething troubles with Grav CMS

Tags: nginx, content-management-system, grav

I have followed the instructions on installing Grav + Admin on by Ubuntu 16.04 server running Nginx [here](https://learn.getgrav.org/basics/installation) and configured + restarted the Nginx server as explained https://learn.getgrav.org/webservers-hosting/servers/nginx.

I then browsed to `https://example.com/` where Grav is installed in the root folder. After going through the process of creating the admin user Grav shows me the Admin dashboard but with empty panels for Maintenance, Statistics etc each of which show a spinner.  Examining the console log I found a 404 error for

```
https://example.com/user/plugins/admin/themes/grav/js/vendor.min.js?04b9d8febd
```

`vendor.min.js` does exist in the said folder and its cousin `admin.min.js?04b9d8febd` is loaded correctly according to the information on the Network tab of my Chrome debugger console.

I had trouble with permissions so I have temporarily recursively `chmod'd` the Grav folder to 777 so I doubt that there is an issue there.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

After examining my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file I have found that it also has the following

```
 location ~ /(\.htaccess|\.git|config|content|content-sample|lib|vendor|CHANGELOG\.md|composer\.(json|lock)){return 404;}

 location ~* /(\.git|cache|bin|logs|backup|tests)/.*$ { return 403; }
 location ~* /(system|vendor)/.*\.(txt|xml|md|html|yaml|yml|php|pl|py|cgi|twig|sh|bat)$ { return 403; }
 location ~* /user/.*\.(txt|md|yaml|yml|php|pl|py|cgi|twig|sh|bat)$ { return 403; }
 location ~ /(LICENSE\.txt|composer\.lock|composer\.json|nginx\.conf|web\.config|htaccess\.txt|\.htaccess) { return 403; }
```

Removing these lines and restarting the server "fixed" the problem but clearly is not a solution. My understanding of nginx configuration directives is rather limited. What do I need to change here so vendor.min.js does not get blocked?